# How to change a div background color when scrolled down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you change the div background color when you scroll down the page.
Example: http://allencreativity.weebly.com/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example :

```
 $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
      var elem = $('.divToChange');
      var hT = elem.offset().top,
          hH = elem.outerHeight(),
          wH = $(window).height(),
          wS = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
               if(wS == hT){
                 elem.css('background-color', 'red');
               }
            }else{
               if (wS > (hT+hH-wH/2)){
                  elem.css('background-color', 'white');
               } 
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery. The `$(document).scrollTop()` returns the value equal to `$(document).height() - $(window).height()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 50){
      $("#myDiv").css('background','red');
    }
    else{
      $("#myDiv").css('background','');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#myDiv{
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  This is my div
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to add the code but an error keeps popping up. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: It's Jquery, make sure you have added this line to your html code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`